# How to send a the same custom response to different incoming SMS texts

Tags: python, sms

What I am trying to do is send the same custom response for different incoming SMS texts such as for the texts saying "yes" or "y" or "Yes" I want to send the same custom response back and then again for "n" or "no" or "No". I still need to fill things out within the code so I have "From Excel" for now until I figure out that part as well. Here is what I have so far just for the responses "Y" and "N".

```
if body == 'Y':
    response = notifications_client.send_sms_notification(
        phone_number='From Excel', 
        template_id='[]', 
)
elif body == 'N':
    response = notifications_client.send_sms_notification(
        phone_number='From Excel', 
        template_id='[]', 
    )
```

Comment: `if body.upper() in ('Y', 'YES'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create two lists to store all combinations of yes and no.

```
for_yes=['y','yes','Yes','Y']
for_no=['n','No','no','N']
```

Then applying this condition.

```
if body in for_yes:
    response
elif body in for_no:
    response
```